# Animations combine by themselves

Tags: animation, armature, actions

My animations keep combining with each other for some reason! This problem has persisted with several models and with many versions of Blender. I've made a simple animated model to demonstrate this issue:

[image: The model in base form viewed from front. No animations activated]

*The model in base form viewed from front. No animations activated*

I've made six animations, three for both bones. Each animation is supposed to move the single bone around some axis.

[image: Oikea means right, vasen means left]

*Oikea means right, vasen means left*

I've saved the animations with push down. However, when I exit and start the Blender again:

[image: The Right_X animation merged with Left_Z. Note that action editor only shows the right bone's keyframe, even tough the left bone moves as well.]

*The Right_X animation merged with Left_Z. Note that action editor only shows the right bone's keyframe, even tough the left bone moves as well.*

All animations have merged with an animation that moves the other bone. All right bone animations also do the Left_Z and left bone ones the Right_Z. Can anyone explain why this kind of thing keeps happening and if there's any fix for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you push down an action, it will appear in the *NLA* as a strip and this strip will be played, unless, in the *Dope Sheet*, in your new action, you've keyframed the same bones, in that case these *Dope Sheet* keyframes will be prioritized.

So you either need to click on *Stash* instead of *Push Down* (and the strip will be muted), or in the *NLA* mute the strip you've already pushed down, or, if you have no particular reason to put your actions in the *NLA*, simply click on the *Fake User* button (shield icon), to make sure that your action will still be available when you'll reopen the file:

[image]

You can play all the actions you want, they are still available in the *Dope Sheet* if you switch it to *Action Editor* mode. But if you have strip playing in the *NLA* you first need to mute them, otherwise they may also play with the selected action (or simply remove the tracks or the strips of the *NLA*):

[image]

Comment: Okay I managed to mute the NLA track. But now I have to put it back on whenever I want to play the track at all. Why the heck is this built so inconveniently? Why can't I just play one animation at a time?

Comment: i'm not sure what you mean, you can play one action at a time, either play it in the nla or play it in the Dope Sheet, but do you have a reason to use the nla? or all these actions or tracks in the nla? if not, remove the strips or tracks

Comment: Do you call Action Editor NLA? In it I have to mute every track for bones that I don't want to move in the current animation, and that is awfully inconvenient. If there's any option to play just the current animation with all other bones staying still, I'm all ears. Also Dope Sheet doesn't have the animation list.

Comment: the NLA is the Nonlinear Animation editor, if you press the Push Down button it creates an action strip in the NLA and this action is playing over the action that you'll load in the Dope Sheet, so I'm not sure why you Push Down if you don't want the action to play

Comment: Well I've pushed down since some of the animations wouldn't be saved otherwise.

Comment: of course they are saved if you press Stach instead (which pushes the action in the NLA but keep it muted) or simply click on the Fake User button as I show in my answer

Comment: Okay, are you saying that I can't play a single animations that I've pushed down anymore, unless I mute each unused bone's track. I should've used stash or fake user in the first place, and there's no fixing it?

Comment: you can play all the actions you want, they are still available in the Dope Sheet if you switch it to Action Editor mode. But if you have strip playing in the NLA you first need to mute them, otherwise they may also play with the selected action

Comment: please see my edit, maybe you haven't understood yet how Dope Sheet and NLA are working

Comment: Okay, finally discovered the nonlinear animation editor based on the picture. Thanks for your patience!